# Solve the inequality $\sqrt{4x+1}+\sqrt{x+1}<x+1$

Tags: inequality, radicals

Can you show the steps for solving this inequality:
$$\sqrt{4x+1}+\sqrt{x+1}<x+1$$

Condition: 
$x \geq -1/4$ and $x\geq -1$.

I'm stuck here:

$$2\cdot \sqrt{(4x+1)(x+1)}<x^2-3x-1$$

Comment: What have you tried so far? You can edit your question to show that, and we'll be better able to help you.

Comment: Please put your question *into* the text here. And perhaps a more descriptive title..

Comment: both conditions together give $$x\geq -\frac{1}{4}$$

Answer (score 3):

We have
$$
x\geq -\frac{1}{4} \;,
$$
and after squaring one times (all terms are non negative) we obtain
$$
4x+1+x+1+2\sqrt{x+1}\sqrt{4x+1}<x^2+2x+1 \;.
$$
Simplifiying, we get
$$
2\sqrt{x+1}\sqrt{4x+1}<x^2-3x-1 \;.
$$
For the right hand side to be nonnegative, we have
$$
x\geq \frac{1}{2}(3+\sqrt{13}) \;.
$$
Now we can square it again:
$$
4(x+1)(4x+1)<(x^2-3x-1)^2 \;.
$$
Simplification gives
$$
{x}^{4}-6\,{x}^{3}-9\,{x}^{2}-14\,x-3 >0 \;,
$$
and this inequality gives the solution:
$$
x>7.46 \ldots
$$